# LSTM multi task learning functional api keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have 2 train values X_data, B_data. I want 2 shared lstm layers to predict 2 outputs for X_data and B_data

```
l1 = layers.LSTM(40)(X_data)
flat_layer = Flatten()(l1)
l2 = layers.LSTM(20)(B_data)
flat_layer2 = Flatten()(l2)


output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(flat_layer)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(flat_layer2)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[X_data,B_data], outputs=[output1,output2])
```

I take this erorr
`AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.`
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that `keras.Model(inputs)` does not take in the input *data* but the input *layer* (just as you did correctly with `outputs`). The data is passed via `model.fit()`. So first of all, you'll need two `Input` layers:

```
X_data = np.random.uniform(0,1,(3,100,40))
B_data = np.random.uniform(0,1,(3,100,20))

y1 = np.random.uniform(0,1,(3,1))
y2 = np.random.uniform(0,1,(3,1))

i1 = Input((100,40)) # you need input layers
i2 = Input((100,20))

l1 = LSTM(40)(i1)
flat_layer = Flatten()(l1)
l2 = LSTM(20)(i2)
flat_layer2 = Flatten()(l2)


output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(flat_layer)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(flat_layer2)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[i1,i2], outputs=[output1,output2])
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
model.fit(x=[X_data,B_data], y=[y1,y2]) # this is where you pass input (data) and output (labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My dataframe just like this and i convert for input data

```
trainxx=np.array(trainn3)
X_data = trainxx.reshape((trainxx.shape[0], 1, trainxx.shape[1]))
```

y values are numpy  array

```
ytrainxx=np.array(ytrains)
```

And your input solution i can't convert it